# ShinyBS package won't update

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to run my shiny app,

```r
runApp()
```

I get the following error. I have tried updating shinyBS and all other packages in use but I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.

> Error in ..stacktraceon..({ :
> Please upgrade package 'shinyBS', see 'requirements.R'

Comment: try physically deleting the folder where the package is